# why does this setTimeout() call work in the console but not as a greasemonkey script?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, settimeout

When I use a setTimeout() in a for() loop in a greasemonkey script, it doesn't appear to work at all.  However, the exact same code works fine if I run it in the Firebug console.  Here's the code:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           setTimeout test
// @include        *
// @run-at         document-end
// ==/UserScript=


function test(delaytime) {
    alert("test called with "+delaytime);
}

function test2() {
  for( var i = 0; i < 100; i+= 10 ) {
    setTimeout('test('+i+');', i);
  }
}

setTimeout(test2,10);
```

If I replace the for() loop with explicit calls like the following, then it works fine.

```
setTimeout(function() { test( 0); },  0);
setTimeout(function() { test(10); }, 10);
setTimeout(function() { test(20); }, 20);
setTimeout(function() { test(30); }, 30);
setTimeout(function() { test(40); }, 40);
setTimeout(function() { test(50); }, 50);
setTimeout(function() { test(60); }, 60);
setTimeout(function() { test(70); }, 70);
setTimeout(function() { test(80); }, 80);
setTimeout(function() { test(90); }, 90);
```

What's the difference?  Is there any way I can get the for loop generated setTimeouts to work in greasemonkey?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because when the string is evaled at the time the setTimeout fires in order to execute the function, the loop has run it's course and `i` is sitting at the last value of the loop.

To freeze the value of `i` for each call to setTimeout, you need to capture it in a function closure like this:

```
function test2() {
  for( var i = 0; i < 100; i+= 10 ) {
    setTimeout(function(val) {
        return(function() {test(val);});
    } (i), i);
  }
}
```

This also has the advantage of getting rid of the eval in the setTimeout parameter.

Comment: like the other suggestion, this gives me the values out of order. IOW, my alerts provide the values in this order: 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 60, 80, 90, 70, 50. (the order varies from run to run). ? Is there a way to do this so that they come out in order?

Comment: Please stop using alerts and use console.log() so the code can actually run real time.  They come out in order for me using my code here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/AyrBa/.  Also note that some small values for the time in `setTimeout()` may be collapsed all to the same minimum value.

Comment: But the when the timeouts trigger they will basically be evaling 'test(0)', 'test(10)', etc., not 'test(i)'. The original code is calling setTimeout with a string and concatenating the value of i into that string...

Comment: No, the _value_ of `i` was being concatenated into the string along with the function name and then passed to `setTimeout()`. From the original question: `'test('+i+');'` would produce a string `'test(0);'` (the first time through the loop). And assuming the question hasn't been edited in between when you and I read it.

Comment: @nnnnnn - Yeah, I see what you're saying now.

Answer (score 1):

You have to duplicate the value of `i` into a locally scoped variable:

```
function test2() {
  for( var i = 0; i < 100; i+= 10 ) {
    (function(i){
        setTimeout('test('+i+');', i);
    })(i);
  }
}
```

**On a side note:** You should pass an anonymous function to `setTimeout` instead of passing it a string (which will be eval'ed). It's much faster this way:

```
function test2() {
    for( var i = 0; i < 100; i+= 10 ) {
        (function(i){
            setTimeout(function(){
                test(i);
            }, i);
        })(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: this gives me the values out of order.  IOW, my alerts provide the values in this order: 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 60, 80, 90, 70, 50.  (the order varies from run to run).  ?

Comment: @mix - 10 seconds is too short for Javascript to guarantee the execution time. `In order to understand how the timers work internally there's one important concept that needs to be explored: timer delay is not guaranteed. Since all JavaScript in a browser executes on a single thread asynchronous events (such as mouse clicks and timers) are only run when there's been an opening in the execution.` http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/

Comment: What difference does duplicating i make when the original code is passing setTimeout a _string_ that looks like 'test2(0);', 'test2(10);', etc., _not_ passing 'test2(i);'?